# Rails 3 friendly way of representing object state which doesn't change

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Is there rails 3 way of representing enum like values on the model.

i.e If I have `Affiliate` model and I have affiliate from web app, or mobile app or other type.

So I can do something like :

```
affiliate.from_web?
affiliate.from_app?
```

Any suggestions?

**Edit:**
I like the offered answer below, and I just wanted to wait a bit longer to see any more opinions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replicate some of the functionality pretty easily. Let's assume you have an `Affiliate` model with a `source` Integer attribute:

```
class Affiliate < ActiveRecord::Base
  SOURCES = {web: 0, mobile: 1, other: 2}

  def source
    SOURCES.key(read_attribute(:source))
  end

  def source?(s)
    SOURCES[s] == read_attribute(s)
  end

  def source=(s)
    write_attributes(:source, SOURCE[s])
  end

end
```

Now you can use it like so:

```
affiliate = Afilliate.new
affiliate.source = :web
affiliate.source # => :web
affiliate.source?(:web) # => true
affiliate.source?(:mobile) # => false
```